"What" or "which" in questions presuming picking out object(s) in mind first and identifying their belonging to some class in the definitive answer
I have two subtly different situations.

There are two pictures in one of which some (living) things are present that are absent in the other. How should one correctly put questions of this type: "What are those two animals that are present in picture A and are absent in picture B?" Or shall it definitively be: "Which are those two animals that are present in picture A and are absent in picture B?" (a possible answer could be something like: "They are a duck and a cow")
In a picture is a set of animals of different sizes figured. Which question would be correct? "What are those two biggest animals that you can see in the picture?" Or "Which are those two biggest animals that you can see in the picture?" (a possible answer could be: "They are a rhino and a hippo")

At first, answering such questions one has to pick out two animals (in mind) and thus it seems to require using "which" in the question. But in the definitive answer the respondent is expected to identify their belonging to some class or species and pronounce only it. This comports with a "what"-question better.

[up a creek without a paddle] This is obviously asking for edits and therefore does not meet the criteria for questions on this site. Sorry. Perhaps you could edit it and just ask about the difference between what and which? Also, please show research on this subject.

In both cases I would understand "What are those two animals...?" to mean "What species of animal are they?". The second question should begin "Which animals...?" - asking you to point out the individual animals.


You are asking which of these two questions is correctly phrased:


What are those two animals that are present in picture A and are absent in picture B?
Which are those two animals that are present in picture A and are absent in picture B?


Actually, you could begin your question with either word; however, you would want to rephrase them slightly to make them sound more natural:


What two animals in picture A are absent in picture B?
Which two animals in picture A are absent in picture B?


(Answer: The duck and the cow.)
Note: We wouldn't need to specify those in the question, although we could ask:


Which of those animals are missing in picture B?



Your second question is a little trickier, but you'd still want to rephrase the questions to make them sound more natural:


What are those two biggest animals that you can see in the picture?
Which are those two biggest animals that you can see in the picture?



Again, you can use either word to start the question, but this time the wording will change slightly depending on which word you use:


What are the two biggest animals in the picture?
Which of the animals in this picture are the two biggest?


The answer to either of those questions would be, "The rhino and the hippo."
Unfortunately, I can't think of any easy rule that would tell you the subtle differences between what and which in all questions like these. Oftentimes, either word can be used, although sometimes the question would need to be worded slightly differently depending on which word you pick.
Which tends to imply there is a choice between a finite number of options, but what can still be used in such situations:


Which is your favorite ELL question?
What is your favorite ELL question?


Both of those are grammatical and idiomatic, but I think which would be more likely to be used when the all the possibilities could be seen at the same time and you are asked to choose from those selections.


Which was your favorite painting at the art show?
What is your favorite painting of all time?



J.R.♦ Thank you very much for such an utmostly comprehensive and limpid answer!

J.R.♦ Which article is better to use in an extended answer: "They are a/the rhino and a/the hippo (a/the duck and a/the cow)"?

Because you are referring to a specific duck, cow, rhino, and hippo (that is, the ones in the pictures), then it would be better to use "the" instead of "a": They are the rhino and the hippo; they are the duck and the cow..

♦ I see. To tell the truth, having been in English for more than 40 years so far, I'm still not taking in to the fullest the justification of the indefinite article use in cases other than when it is called for to mean "one". "I can see a duck"=one duck (it sounds good). But "A duck can fly"-it's dubious that every duck can fly or it is only one duck which can fly. In most cases I'd abide by a generic implication of "the". It's like "The apple is salubrious for the person's well-being"-not one apple and not every apple but "apple" in general. So, "The duck can fly", "I am the man"etc

But it's, of course, in my humble oppinion of the non-native speaker ("non-native speaker" in general, as belonging to the class of non-native speakers). If I can afford myself holding forth about such matters at all ))
